# $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_1^N\left(1-\frac{n}{N+1}\right)a_n$ for any positive sequence $\{a_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive sequence. Suppose that
$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_1^N\left(1-\frac{n}{N+1}\right)a_n$ exists. Is the series 
$\sum a_n$ convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $a_n\ge0$ this is trivial. If $\sum a_n$ does not converge then $\sum a_n=+\infty$, and it's obvious that that implies $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_1^N\left(1-\frac{n}{N+1}\right)a_n=\infty$: If $K$ is fixed then $$\liminf_{N\to \infty} \sum_1^N\left(1-\frac{n}{N+1}\right)a_n\ge\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_1^K\left(1-\frac{n}{N+1}\right)a_n=\sum_1^K a_n.$$